# XSLT "Choose-When" to set variable gives different results

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm altering some XSLT and trying to conditionally set a variable using choose-when. Previously the variable was set outright, without conditions.I can't work out why.

Previously it was set via:

```
            <xsl:variable name="fields" select="pubs:field[@name=normalize-space($elements)]" />
```

I have attempted to set $fields using:

```
            <xsl:variable name="fields">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($elements, 'acceptance-date')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="pubs:field[@name=normalize-space($elements)]" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="pubs:field[@name=normalize-space($elements)]" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
```

I expect the rest of my code to continue on as it previously did, I've set it that way for now while experimenting (the select statements are identical). Instead I get an"XPATH error : Invalid type" when the $fields variable is used elsewhere:

```
            <xsl:variable name="field_values" select="$fields/pubs:people/*|$fields/pubs:keywords/*|$fields/pubs:items/*|$fields/*[local-name()!='items' and local-name()!='keywords' and local-name()!='people']" />
```

I'm relatively new to XSLT/XPATH so I'm assuming it's something obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks,
James

Comment: In your first instance, the `fields` variable is referencing the nodes directly. However, in the second instance, `fields` variable is actually a string, because `xsl:value-of` returns the text value of a node, not the node itself. Of course, the easiest answer would be to simply say "don't use `xsl:choose` here" because at the moment your `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise` do the same thing, so it isn't necessary! Perhaps you can give an example where `xsl:otherwise` returned a different result, and then a fuller answer can be given? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example obviously isn't real, because the two branches of the conditional are the same. But in many cases you can do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="x" 
 select="$nodes[contains($elements, 'acceptance-date')] 
       | $other-nodes[not(contains($elements, 'acceptance-date'))]"/>
```

Consider whether you really want to be using XSLT 1.0. Problems like this become so much easier with XSLT 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: Hi Michael, your suggestion was the method that ultimately worked, so thank you. Unfortunately, I think I'm stuck with XSLT 1.0 as this isn't my code and it's part of a larger piece of software. I only feel comfortable altering small pieces of it. Great learning experience though!

Answer (score 0):

What XSLT engine do you use? If it is MS-XSL, you could try to use the node-set() function, like

```
            <xsl:variable name="fields">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($elements, 'acceptance-date')">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="pubs:field[@name=normalize-space($elements)]" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="pubs:field[@name=normalize-space($elements)]" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="field_values" select="msxsl:node-set($fields)/pubs:field/pubs:people/*|msxsl:node-set($fields)/pubs:field/pubs:keywords/*|msxsl:node-set($fields)/pubs:field/pubs:items/*|msxsl:node-set($fields)/pubs:field/*[local-name()!='items' and local-name()!='keywords' and local-name()!='people']" />
```

also add the namespace declaration to the XSLT's root element:

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

Comment: It's still not quite the same as the original, because it's returning a copy of the nodes, not the original nodes. This would affect the outcome if the subsequent processing selects ancestor elements, for example.

Comment: That's definitely true. I generally reckon, if you might need to use the node-set(), it's a time to reconsider the whole XSLT logic and may be implement a completely different approach. But the author said he is altering some existing XSLT, so rewriting it might be not an option and using the node-set() is still good as a temporary solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I attempted it, but couldn't get it to work. I believe I'm using xsltproc. I did eventually manage to do what I needed to after some confusion on my part.